# FullCalendar external event drop two different modals

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

I'm sort of self-teaching myself through trial and error, lots of errors :)  I'm stuck.  I am using fullCalendar which is working great from JSON feeds.

I want to drag external events to the calendar and depending on the event dragged, show a different modal.  The event drop and modal show is working, except its opening both (vacation on top of repair) every time.

```
<div id="external-events">
<div id="vacationdrop" class="fc-event vacation" className="vacation">Vacation</div>
<div id="repairdrop" class="fc-event repair" className="repair">Repair</div
</div>
```

The event drop:

```
drop: function() {
    if (jQuery('#external-events .fc-event').hasClass('repair') {
        var territory = jQuery(terrDropdown).find(':selected').text();
        var start = moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        var end = moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
        jQuery('#calendarRepairModal #startdate').val(start);
        jQuery('#calendarRepairModal #enddate').val(end);
        jQuery('#calendarRepairModal #terr').val(territory);
        jQuery("#calendarRepairModal").modal("show");

      }
    };

    else {

      if (jQuery('#external-events .fc-event').hasClass('vacation') {
          var territory = jQuery(terrDropdown).find(':selected').text();
          var start = moment(start).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
          var end = moment(end).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
          jQuery('#calendarVacationModal #startdate').val(start);
          jQuery('#calendarVacationModal #enddate').val(end);
          jQuery('#calendarVacationModal #terr').val(territory);
          jQuery("#calendarVacationModal").modal("show");
        };)

    },
```

Any help would be appreciated. I did search quite extensively but nothing that resembles my objective. Also, I've written jQuery out each time because I'm also using wordpress, and its finicky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be sure *exactly* why you get the behaviour you describe, because the code in your sample does not compile, however it's clear that

```
jQuery('#external-events .fc-event')
```

will return *all* your external events, because it selects everything within the external-events box which has the `fc-event` class - which is all of them. Then, executing

.hasClass("repair")

on that list of events means it return true if *any* of those events also have the class "repair". So because that's your first `if` statement, it will always display the repair modal if you have at least one "repair" event in your external event list.

I think what you meant to do was identify the specific event which was dragged and dropped. For that you can use the `this` object. As mentioned in the documentation (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dropping/drop/) in the context of the "drop" callback, `this` represents the single element which has been dropped in order to trigger the callback.

e.g.

```
drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui) {
    if ($(this).hasClass('repair')) {
```

and later...

```
if ($(this).hasClass('vacation')) {
```

See a (slightly simplified) demo here http://jsfiddle.net/sbxpv25p/97/ which shows the use of `this`. (I had to guess / just put in basic things) with some of your code, just to make it work, but you can ignore those bits, and focus on the "drop" callback).